# Translation check: "Give in not to apathy, but humanity"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

Would *ne cede apathia sed humanitate* be a sensical translation of "give in not to apathy, but humanity"? I am trying to keep this as few words as possible but without sounding too abrupt. I was also modeling this somewhat off of:

> tu ne cede malis, sed contra audentior ito

-- Virgil, Aeneid, 6, 95:

> you should not give in to evils, but proceed ever more boldly against them

-- Translation from this [list of latin phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(full)#tu_ne_cede_malis,_sed_contra_audentior_ito) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Cedere* takes the dative, so it should be:

> Ne apathiae cede, sed humanitati.

(Liking this word order better, but yours is fine too, of course.)

Other than that, I see no objections. *Apathia* and *humanitas* are fine (no false friends); you could also say *lentitudo* for apathy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By "false friends", you mean that _apathia_ and _humanitas_ work fine as opposites within the sentence, right?

Comment: @Adam False friends are words that look familiar but mean something other than you think they mean, like *fascinare, ignorare* or *compendium*. When translating a Greek or Latin loanword in English, one has to beware of these. But *apathia* and *humanitas* are “true friends” I think.

Comment: Ahh - that has bitten me a few times here and there.